# Is there any way to get country ISO-2 code but from windows properties, NOT from JVM

Tags: java, windows, jvm, locale

Basicly as title states, ive already tried:

```java
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
System.out.println(currentLocale.getDisplayLanguage());
System.out.println(currentLocale.getDisplayCountry());

System.out.println(currentLocale.getLanguage());
System.out.println(currentLocale.getCountry());

System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.country"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.language"));
```

and it all gives me US or english when i have set something totally else in widows settings.
Please give me any advice.
So i would expect to get Contry Code, for example if i have set Poland in system, id expect "PL" but im getting "US"

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you were expecting, and the output you saw instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Java locale is not necessary the same as system locale, as it can be overridden

- with `user.country`, `user.language` and `user.variant` system properties;
- by calling `Locale.setDefault()`.

There is non-standard undocumented API for getting locale information provided by the OS. It is implemented on Windows Vista or later. Try the following snippet.

```
import sun.util.locale.provider.HostLocaleProviderAdapter;

...

    static String getHostCountry() {
        for (Locale locale : new HostLocaleProviderAdapter().getAvailableLocales()) {
            if (!locale.getCountry().isEmpty()) {
                return locale.getCountry();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What about linux?

Comment: @DamianHong-MinhNguyen On Linux just examine `LC_ALL` and `LANG` environment variables.